# Did Hana Hana no Mi give the user superhuman strength?

Tags: one-piece

Hana Hana no Mi is eaten by Nico Robin, as we know that she can grow parts of her body.
She usually grow her hands to attack, or to defend her. She also can swing or lift her or other people with her growing hands.
She can easily break the bones of her opponents, just like when she used clutch or twist.

I know that if her body parts are hurts, she also feels the pain. But is that mean when she used clutch or twist, she used her "normal" human strength?
Because she doesn't seems no trouble when do that to her opponents. Or it's because the Hana Hana no Mi that also give her superhuman strength?

Comment: I don't understand the question. Obviously the plethora of extra limbs magically appearing is a superhuman power.   Are you asking whether the limbs themselves are granted superhuman strength as a result of the fruit (or if the limbs are explicitly duplicates of her own limbs and therefore have her strength)?

Comment: Oh, yeah, I mean her strength, superhuman strength, edited.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are asking whether Robin was given superhuman strength by the fruit's powers, the answer is no. The duplicated limbs she creates are no stronger individually than her normal limbs.

To quote [the One Piece wiki's page on the Hana Hana no Mi](http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Hana_Hana_no_Mi):

> The strength of the user is also still limited to their individual strength, meaning that the individual strength in the replicating appendages is no different to that of Robin's actual corresponding limbs.

However, she can get around that by creating multiple limbs so as to subdue larger people or move heavier objects, as she demonstrated during her fights against Yama and Oars, among others, but even then she has her limits, as she noted how heavy Yama was during her fight with him. The fruit itself doesn't make her any physically stronger, she just uses her powers creatively to make up for her weaknesses.

Comment: ooh okay, I get it, thanks for explanation

Answer (score 0):

I believe it is. Robin will not be able to control such huge limbs if the fruit did not give her any superhuman power. Furthermore, Robin's body is so thin and does not look like she's having any physical training.

Comment: Actually, those huge limbs she creates are not single, extra-large limbs; they're made from several normal-sized limbs that she puts together to form a single large limb. Besides, even if they were a single one, they're still part of her body and not a heavy item, so I assume she'd have no problem moving them anyway.